# Java Rest Upload - how to upload files to an endpoint and bypass these files to a second endpoint?

Tags: java, rest, upload, quarkus, multipart

I want to create an endpoint to upload files and inside this endpoint send these files to another endpoint. Like this:

```
[front-end] ----(files)----> [UploadResource] ----(samefiles)----> [ApiServiceResource]
```

The first endpoint get all files uploaded but sending these files from this endpoint to the second endpoint it receives an empty list.

**imports:**

```
import java.util.List;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.rest.client.inject.RestClient;
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.PartType;
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.RestForm;
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.multipart.FileUpload;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Consumes;
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.Response;
```

**Upload class:**

```
@Path("/v1/upload")
public class UploadResource {
  @Inject
  @RestClient
  ApiService apiService;

  @POST
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public Response uploadFiles(@RestForm(FileUpload.ALL) PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) List<FileUpload> files) {
    System.out.println("endpoint 'v1/upload' received " + files.size() + " files");
    apiService.receiveFiles(files);
    return Response.ok().build();
  }
```

**ApiService interface:**

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "api-service")
public interface ApiService {
  @POST
  @Path("v1/receivefiles")
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  Response receiveFiles(@RestForm(FileUpload.ALL) @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) List<FileUpload> files);
}
```

**ApiServiceResource class:**

```
@Path("/api-service")
public class ApiServiceResource {
  @POST
  @Path("v1/receivefiles")
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
  public Response receiveFiles(@RestForm(FileUpload.ALL) @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) List<FileUpload> files) {
    System.out.println("endpoint 'api-service/v1/receivefiles' received " + files.size() + " files");
    return Response.ok().build();
  }
}
```

After sending a POST request with 3 files to `'.../v1/upload'` the console shows this:

**Console:**

```
endpoint 'v1/upload' received 3 files
endpoint 'api-service/v1/receivefiles' received 0 files
```

*Note*: *If the POST request points directly to `'api-service/v1/receivefiles'` it works fine*

Comment: I actually don't think we support `FileUpload` in the client yet... Mind opening an issue?

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to create a `MessageBodyWriter<FileUpload>`. I've done the opposite for clients consuming `StreamingOutput` - I created a relatively simple `MessageBodyReader<StreamingOutput>`.